# Space Invaders Clone Movement and Spawning Logic

Tags: java, loops

I am making a Space Invaders Clone in Java. I am having a little trouble working out the movement and spawning of the invaders loop. I want them to spawn, check for the edge of the screen and have basic movement.

I know how to make images move when they are just single objects, but these will be more than one obviously. I don't want to have to move each one individually as that would make for some messy code and slow me down a lot.

It is basically a group of images loaded into my `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. So if there is a basic loop that can generate these images and allow me to move them like they would in the original Space Invaders that would be great!

So far I am painting the Invaders like so:

```
g.drawImage(invaderGreen.draw(), 100, 100, this);
g.drawImage(invaderGreen.draw(), 100, 100, this);
g.drawImage(invaderGreen.draw(), 100, 100, this);
g.drawImage(invaderGreen.draw(), 100, 100, this);
g.drawImage(invaderGreen.draw(), 100, 100, this);
//etc etc.
```

(I am aware I need to change the X and Y variables, this is just an example.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code of what you've tried and what your specific issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your invaders inside a list or array.

```
List<InvaderGreen> invaders = new ArrayList<InvaderGreen>();
...

//spawn intial game state
invaders.add(new InvaderGreen(...)); //Hint: loop if you are creating 1+
```

Then update the game state & draw the screen using a loop:

```
for (InvaderGreen oneInvader : invaders){
    oneInvader.move(); // let every invader calculate its new position
    oneInvader.drawSelf(graphics); //let every invader draw itself using Graphics g
}
```

You might want to create some kind of GameState object and pass that into the move method:
 `oneInvader.move(gamestate);`

Comment: This question is over a year and a half old, I no longer require an answer, thank you for your suggestion.